# Are there any disadvantages of having many solder joints on a single wire?

Tags: soldering

I was working on this project where I have to connect multiple wires from a single supply wire. Are there any dis advantages of having many solder joints on a single wire?

Answer (score 10):

Multiple exposed joints that need to be heat shrunk or tapped up. A broken jacket in multiple places causing the wire to be weaker. Even daisy chained crimps or solders make the wire weaker. A mess to fix if you need to in the future. And worst of all, it looks ugly and unprofessional.

If you need to solder multiple times to the same wire, consider using an in-between, like a terminal strip, or a pcb, or something solid. Or use more wires to the board. Look at professional pcbs like in ATX Power Supplies. Multiple wires needed to the same supply? Multiple wires to the board. The only wires that are daisy chained are the power to the hard drives, and those are professionally crimped and soldered.

[image]

A non standard splitter (too many connectors) but the general idea:

[image]

Also consider other means of connecting the wires. Crimping, Taps, Spade connectors, even Screw Caps. Soldering isn't the only or even the best method.

Comment: Thanks very much. In our project we are having a circular disc. So, I was planning to have a circular wire of lesser radius for the sake of supplying power supply. I am planning to connect the LEDs through the circular supply wire in a radially outwards fashion. I think there would be a space constraint if I use taps and spade connectors instead of soldering. Could you please elaborate on "wire becoming weaker"  when soldered at multiple places.

Comment: @vikas a smaller wire will suffer from heat or mechanical fatigue. But the way you describe is different. Your making a ring for power? Like the spokes of a bicycle wheel? Just use a larger gauge stiff wire.